# Connection Strings and Dapper

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, connection-string

I am trying to connect to an SQL db to extract data and I am using Dapper for the process. I assume I am having some problems with the connection string; I am trying to access a remote sql server 2012 db but my connection keeps failing:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Dapper;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Data_Connection
{
  public static class Program
  {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

            string connetionString = null;
            SqlConnection cnn ;
                  connetionString = "Server=datanet.local.net/datadb; Database=ddata;Trusted_Connection=True";
            cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
            try
            {
                cnn.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection Open !");
                cnn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Can not open connection !");
            }

    }

  }
}
```

I have never tried connecting to an sql db using c# and I am fairly new to the environment. Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: _"connection keeps failing"_ with what error? Have you tried `select * from dbo.data ...`?

Comment: Not sure `Server=data.local.net\datadb` makes any sense, especially if you list the database again later on.  What database are you trying to select from?

Comment: The title is misleading.  Although the OP intends on using dapper when the connection issue is resolved, this question is simply "how do I connect to a database using c# .net". I'd start from the top https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?q=connecting%20to%20a%20database%20c%23%20.net with google.

Comment: " I assume I am having some problems with the connection string;" -  before assuming, why not change the line in your `catch` clause to `Console.WriteLine(ex)`? It should tell you what went wrong.

Comment: if open/close doesn't work, it isn't a dapper question. So: what is `ex.Message`?

Comment: I had a problem with the connection string.. after several permutations it finally worked.. I found the necessary info from connectionstrings.com, thanks everyone